# how to exclude checking words in quotations using java

Tags: quotes

It's the first time I'm doing this so I didn't want to be lengthy. I'm building a cross reference from reading a java program. I'm to exclude java keywords, commented words and words in quotations. I got through with excluding the java keywords and the commented words but I'm having problems excluding those in quotes.

```
public class CrossReference {
static Scanner in;
static PrintWriter out;
static int currentLine = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    in  = new Scanner (new FileReader("keywords.txt"));
    out = new PrintWriter (new FileWriter("crossreference.out"));
    LinkedList keywords = new LinkedList();
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        String word = in.nextLine();
        keywords.addTail(new NodeData(word));
    }
    in  = new Scanner (new FileReader("program.txt"));
    BinaryTree bst = new BinaryTree();
    while(in.hasNextLine()){
        String line = in.nextLine();
        out.printf("%3d. %s\n", ++currentLine,line);
        getWordsOnLine(line,bst,keywords);
    }
    out.printf("\nWords                LineNumber\n\n");
    bst.inOrder();
    out.close();
}

public static void getWordsOnLine(String inputLine, BinaryTree bst, LinkedList keywords){
    Scanner inLine = new Scanner(inputLine);
    inLine.useDelimiter("[^a-zA-Z//\"*]+");
    boolean b = true;
    while(inLine.hasNext() && b){
        String word = inLine.next().toLowerCase();
        if (word.contains("/") || word.contains("\"") || word.contains("*")) {
            b = false;
        } //this works for the commented words but not so well for the ones in quotes as it also excludes words after those in quotes
        else {
            boolean key = false;
            Node curr = keywords.head;
            while (curr != null) {
                if (curr.data.str.equals(word)) key = true;
                curr = curr.next;
            }
            if (key == false) {
                TreeNode node = bst.findOrInsert(new TreeNodeData(word));
                ListNode p = new ListNode(currentLine);
                p.next = node.data.firstLine;
                node.data.firstLine = p;
            }
        }  
    }    
}
```

}

Comment: Include the code you have so far and what you have tried. We aren't here to make your homework.

Comment: Define *in your question* what a `word` is.

Comment: um. In which language?

Answer (score 0):

1. Split your string by space into an array.
2. Iterate through the array, checking which elements start with quotes and are words
3. Sum it

So the code would look like:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String a = "COPY PASTE ORIGINAL HERE";
    String[] arr = a.split(" ");
    int count = 0;
    for(String each: arr){
      if(each.charAt(0) != '\"' && each.charAt(0) < '0' || each.charAt(0) > '9'){ 
        count++;
      }
    }
    System.out.println("words="+count);
  }
}
```